# Why is complexity of DFS is O(V^2) in adjacency matrix and O(V+E) in adjacency list representation?

Tags: graph

Why DFS algorithm is having O(V<sup>2</sup>) compelxity in adjacency matrix representation and O(V+E) in adjacency list representations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how time complexity of bfs and dfs depends upon graph representation being used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925009/how-time-complexity-of-bfs-and-dfs-depends-upon-graph-representation-being-used)

Answer (score 13):

For matrix:

There is one row and one column for each vertex. Position i,j contains 1 if there is an edge from vertex i to vertex j.

The size of the whole matrix is |V|^2

Why the complexity is |V|^2?

Because each position in the matrix is visited once.

For adjacency linked list:

Collection of linked lists with one list for each vertex such that the list for vertex v is the list of all vertices adjacent to vertex v.

Why the complexity is |E|+|V|?
Because each position in the adjacency linked list is visited once and there are |V| vertices and |E| edges.

Answer (score 0):

Given a graph = 〈, 〉, what is to be the running time of the depth‐first search algorithm, as a function of the number of nodes  = || and edges  =||, if the input graph is represented by an adjacency matrix instead of an adjacency list?

Answer: If the input graph is represented by an adjacency matrix instead of an adjacency list then the running times change from O(n+m) to O(n^2). This is because the adjacency matrix consists of one row and one column for each node and the index i,j stores 1 if there is an edge from node i to j(as shown in Fig-1). Therefore,  the DFS algorithm makes the stack call for all the given n nodes n times to find out which node is adjacent to it.